# ¿Es posible extraer el código fuente (base) de un archivo JSON de una web?

Tags: json

Tengo éste enlace: http://api.formice.com/mouse/stats.json

```
{"error":"Mouse not found"}
```

¿Es posible extraer de alguna forma el código fuente (base) que está alojado en ese archivo?

Comment: @pyYuir f12 o ctrl+i

Comment: Si te refieres al código fuente que se ejecuta en el servidor y que genera ese JSON: no

Answer (score 0):

Si usted no es el dueño de ese servidor, no es posible. Eso es porque la repuesta contiene sólo esa cadena `{"error":"Mouse not found"}`. El codigo utilizado por el servidor envió ese mensaje, pero el código no es público.

Para obtener más informacion, usted podría probar enviar unas solicitudes con [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Las repuestas que daría el servidor a mensajes diferentes le podría dar una idea de cómo funciona esta API.